# Where can I find the mysqlbinlog file format?

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

Is there a place where I can find the mysqlbinlog file format?  I'm writing some scripts to move updates into another format, and it would be really nice not to have to parse mysqlbinlog output comments.

Comment: It is possible to understand the native format of MySQL binlogs, assuming you're not busy for about a month. :)  But, if you'll explain in a little more detail what you mean by "move updates into another format" then I should be able to suggest some resources that might be useful.  It's a pretty tightly-packed format and is not well-documented, but it can be deciphered.